# decrypting LUKS with trezor/ ledger

Tags: disk-encryption, luks

With trezor it is possible to ecnrypt & decrypt encfs like this 

`encfs --standard --extpass=./encfs_aes_getpass.py ~/.crypt ~/crypt`

the script is here

`https://github.com/trezor/python-trezor/blob/master/tools/encfs_aes_getpass.py`

I wonder if it'd be possible to set external device as source of the password while setting up LUKS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

`cryptsetup` has option `--key-file` where you can pass your key (generated by a Trezor device) to.

Here's a working example: https://github.com/xaionaro-go/trezorLuks